# How to deal with object type properties in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In the below scenario, the Field class has 2 properties DataType which is enum and Value as object type. How should I create SQL tables for the below classes using Entity Framework? Kindly explain in detail as I am new to MVC.

Note: I am able to create SQL tables with any predefined datatype(using mvc code first) and also enum, however I have no clue on how to implement object type properties. Here the Field table should accommodate huge number of columns. Also is there a way I can use Dictionary to implement Value. Or can this be achieved using any other ORM.

```
public class Data
{
public string name {get; set;}
public Field Value {get;set;}
}

public class Field
{
public DataType datatype {get;set;}
public object Value {get; set;}
}
public class Field<T> : Field
{
T Value {get; set;}
}
```

@Abdulmalek Albakkar, I already have an asp.net code for which I am trying to build a db schema. The properties are coming from business logic that is why they are not very db friendly.
Let me try explaining with an example below, the first table(Person) is like an index which stores person name(string) and fields which take details about person(class object).

```
public class Person
{
public string name {get; set;}
public Field Value {get;set;}
}
```

the second table(GetPersonDetail)is a linked to Person table which has a single column which can take any datatype and its value

```
public class GetPersonDetail
{
public object Value {get; set;}
}
```

For each person there should be only one table with only one row and all the person detail should be fetched from GetPersonDetail table, i.e;

```
**Value**                       
FirstName:Sam                       
LastName:Wolsh                      
Age:21                      
Salary:3000                     
Weight:55                       
Hobby:Singing                       

**Name  FirstName   LastName    Age Salary  Weight  Hobby**
  Sam   Sam         Wolsh       21  3000    55      Singing


**Value**           
NickName:Bob            
Height:160          
Interest:Travel         

**Name  NickName    Height  Interest**
  Bobby Bob         168     Travel
```

Here the person should be allowed to enter whatever details they want to feed in GetPersonDetail table, all the details collected in a single column should then be auto pivoted as columns in Person table as mentioned above. Can this scenario be achieved in MVC?

Comment: What do you really want to store in that column ? If you are using code first, it will create the table(s) for you.

Comment: Thanks for responding... Well in this example I need create a main table named Data which has two columns name and Value. And another table name Field which can get many values from user dynamically. Lets say I have user1 and user1 can have many fields(in value column which should be populated from Field table). example user1 choose to enter 3 values age(int), DOB(date), salary(double) and other user2 wants to enter 10 different information. Thus I want a table which is not confined to specific length of column, but should be able to grow as per user entered detail. Can this be achieved?

Comment: If you want a system where each user can enter a variable amount of name-value pairs where the values are different types, you might want to look at something other than a relational database.  While what you describe can be done with a relational database, it's *extremely* difficult to query.

Comment: Thanks Ann.. however I am using SQL server environment thus I might not be able to move to any other non relational db. Is there any other way (or technology) to achieve this scenario?

Comment: If your company is open to using Azure, Azure DocumentDB sounds like a good fit for your data storage needs.  See here:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-introduction/

Comment: If not, then tell me: does the user have absolute freedom to name their name-value-pairs, or do they pick from a pre-defined set?  Can a new user come along at any time, or do they get added only every so often? Does their setup (defining the data for this user) require IT involvement, or does it have to be totally self-serve?

Answer (score 0):

**Generic Classes are not Supported In EF**

I think I got that before
You probably should create three classes
Let's say we are dealing with Accounts so..
our classes are Accounts, Details , AccountDetails

```
Account:ID,Name 
Detail: ID,Name , Type(enum)
AccountDetail: ID, AccountID , DetailID , Value [object]
```

and then, when the user enters detail which is not exist, we added it to details first then make a relation between that account and the detail we inserted

```
Account: 1, John
Detail: 1, Age , Int(enum)[0,1,2...etc]
AccountDetail:1,1,1,24
```

And then, depending on your type (enum) you make your validation about the input (value)

when the user enters detail we already have, we just have to get its ID from our Database and make a relation with that account

Comment: Thanks Abdul for responding.. however in this case I am trying to create a new database schema with two column to feed the data from user as these data will be used for analysis purpose. Do you suggest any other way to achieve this, as EF doesn't support generic classes?

Comment: Maybe if u explained your situation more, I could be useful and help :)
Why new schema and what exactly "to feed the data from user"
I still don't know exactly what do you want to do

Comment: Hi Abdul.. Since my message was too long I couldn't comment here.. I have given a detailed message on top. Please give it a glance. Any help is greatly appreciated.